# Ethernet/H/W utility that determines whether or not a PC / the OS has Auto-MDIX

Tags: network-manager, hardware

What is an Ethernet or H/W utility that can determine whether or not a PC and/or the OS has Auto-MDIX (Automatic Medium-Dependent Interface Crossover) feature that allows to automatically detect and configure the appropriate cabling type, straight-through or crossover

Comment: Might be a hardware thing rather than involving any OS - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium-dependent_interface